# Odd user display discrepancy in standalone Samba server ("Account Unknown" vs "Unix User")

Tags: samba, samba4

I am using a standalone Samba server on Ubuntu 18.04 (Samba 4.7.6). When an employee leaves the company, their Unix account ist locked (but not deleted). Their Samba account, however, is deleted via `smbpasswd -x foo`. When viewing the properties of a shared file owned by a deleted user from Windows, the owner is displayed as `foo (Unix User\foo)`. However, there is one deleted user that is displayed as `Account Unknown (S-...)`. Where does this discrepancy come from and can it be "fixed"? Additionally, I noticed that the last four digits of the SIDs don't match the Unix UIDs. Is that normal? Side note: the user's have all been added via `smbpasswd -a foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a caching issue. After a couple of days, the problem resolved itself.